# Instantiate multiple classes from a single generic overide style class

Tags: c#, class, interface, instantiation

I am looking for a way to be able to instantiate multiple classes that have the same method.

looking to do something where I can pass in the name of the class as a string.  Here is what I have so far while it compiles it will not run as I am not instantiating the class correctly.

Im doing something like this but I know I am missing something. If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

```
public class useMyClass{
   public runMyClass(string st1, list<string> mysts, string myClass){
       classProcessor cp = new myClass1(); // this works
       classProcessor cp = new myClass2(); // this works

       // Here I just want to be able to do using the string variable myClass (myClass1 or myClass2 ) could be the string value
       //classProcessor cp = new Class(myClass);

       // This does not work always null
       classProcessor cp = (classProcessor)System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(myClass);
       cp.myMethod(st1,mysts);
   }
}
```

file1: classProccessor.cs

```
public interface classProccessor{
    public void myMethod(string st1, list<string> mysts);
}
```

file2: myClass1.cs

```
public class myclass1 : classProccessor{ 
    public void myMethod(string st1, list<string> mysts){
      //do something;
    }
}
```

file3: myClass2.cs

```
public class myclass2 : classProccessor{ 
    void myMethod(string st1, list<string> mysts){
        // do something different;
    }
}
```

How can I create a new instance of a class using the string name of the class through the use of the interface?  I know I must be missing something simple.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: When I run through the program i get a null reference exception<code>     classProcessor cp = (classProcessor)System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(myClass);  // makes it past here
       cp.myMethod(st1,mysts); // says null reference exception use "new" keyword</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces don't happen automatically.
You need to explicitly implement the interface in each class:

```
public clas MyClass1 : IClassProcessor
```

Comment: with this added on the class for my interface, I still get a null return instead of it instantiating a new class

Comment: @user2300516: Then your type name wasn't found.  Make sure it includes the namespace, and that you're looking in the correct assembly.

Comment: I have all of these files living in the same name space, and they all have the same using libraries.

Comment: @user2300516: It doesn't matter.  You must pass the full namespace to `CreateInstance()`.

Comment: I plugged into the full name space "MyNameSpace.Processors.MyClass1" and still null.  The orginating call comes from a webservice to this library, then I am doing this portion of the interface to classes, but maybe the assembly im just not sure

Comment: classProcessor cp = (classProcessor)System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("MyNameSpace.process.myClass1");

Comment: @user2300516: Are they defined in the same assembly?

Comment: I am guessing so, I started with a webapplication, then added a webservice to it.  I then added a new project to that which created a new solution.  The webservice portion does have a different namespace but all the classes besides the webservice are in the second namespace/project.  The webservice just makes the call to ActionProcessor. which is everything posted here

Comment: @user2300516: You need to start from the assembly that contains the type.  (eg, `typeof(Whatever).Assembly`)

Comment: I have the interface so it will call any of the class directly.

Comment: I know I can do 

    IClassProcessor icp = new MyClass1;

but I want to do this where the class name is a string value

    string strNewClassName = "MyClass1";
    IClassProcessor icp = new strNewClassName; where this string becomes a new class

Comment: @user2300516: You need to start from the assembly that contains the type. (eg, `typeof(Whatever).Assembly`)

Comment: I tried to use the typeof().Assembly.CreateInstance(strNewClassName) but I am not sure what should go into the typeof().  Library, assembly, class.

Comment: I was looking over this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262693/c-sharp-using-activator-createinstance?answertab=active#tab-top am I missing something here or can I do this with out the use of these Factories like I am.

Comment: I added a factory class using a map to create the instance for now, but I think I could solve this dynamically if I can figure out how to pass typeof the string value or get the typeof a class from the string name of the class

Comment: @user2300516: You just need to get the correct assembly.  You can use `typeof(SomeClass).Assembly` to get the assembly containing `SomeClass`.  What don't you understand?