# C# make generic method that knows how to call function on "some" class

Tags: c#, generics

is it possible to make generic function in c# that get as input some class and method (of the class) and parameters to the method ( and maybe the result type ) and make instance of that class and call to the function of the class with the parameters and return the result?

Comment: You should be able to do it with reflection

Comment: can you add code please...

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.getconstructor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.getconstructor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: When you say "get as input... method", do you mean a string containing the method name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int TestMethod(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int result = ExecuteMethod<Test, int>("TestMethod", 1, 2);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static TResult ExecuteMethod<TClass, TResult>(string methodName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        // Instantiate the class (requires a default parameterless constructor for the TClass type)
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<TClass>();

        // Gets method to execute
        var method = typeof(TClass).GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Executes and returns result
        return (TResult)method.Invoke(instance, parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless Reflection is your absolute option, use one of the following delegates:

- [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): Will let you execute a method that does not return a value. There are several overloads that will let you pass in additional arguments.
- [`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): Will let you execute a method that returns a result of type `TResult`. There are more overloads that will let you pass in additional arguments. They all follow the syntax `Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult>` and so on.
- And finally, you can define your own delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You can do that with reflection.

Here you have a few useful links

[Create an instance with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263665/1322417)

[How to invoke method with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202430/1322417)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you create an instance of a class using reflection and then call a method on that class.

Assuming you have a class:

```
public class MyType
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

You could do the following:

```
Type instanceType = Type.GetType("MyType");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(instanceType);

MethodInfo method = instanceType.GetMethod("MethodName");
object returnValue = method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { /* paramaters go here */ });
```